# text underscore groups with caption

Tags: text, grouping

I am trying to achieve what I have called the underscore groups with caption. I don't know the exact name and I have tried to search on the internet for this, without any success.

Here is an image describing visually what I mean:

[image: underscore groups with caption]

Can anyone give me LaTeX code how to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool for what you want is the `\underbracket` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \[ \underbracket[0.6pt]{0}_{\min} \underbracket[0.6pt]{1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,7\,8\,9\ldots72\,73}_{\text{number domain}} \underbracket[0.6pt]{74}_{\max}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Marijn: One of my usual typos… Thanks for warning me!

Comment: I am also trying to center this text. I have tried with a `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` and also with `\centering` but none seem to work. Any help here? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @alexandre1985: Do as I did: use `\[ … \]`, it will be automatically centred. –

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with tikz

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \inteval \int_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\test}[1]
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] (start) at (0,0) {0}; 
    \node[] (mid)   at (3,0) {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... \inteval{#1-1} #1};
    \node[] (end)   at (6,0){\inteval{#1+1}};
    \foreach \x in {start,mid,end}
    \draw[] (\x.north west) -- (\x.south west) --(\x.south east) -- (\x.north east);
    \node[scale=0.8] at ([yshift = -0.25cm]start.south){min};
    \node[scale=0.8] at ([yshift = -0.25cm]mid.south){number domain};
    \node[scale=0.8] at ([yshift = -0.25cm]end.south){max};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\test{18}
\par 
\test{74}
\par 
\test{23}
\end{document}
```

the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I find the other answer more visually appealing.